# CentOS 7 MariaDB 10 Remote Connection Setup

Tags: mariadb, centos7

I've been setting up MariaDB 10 on CentOS 07.   I'm having difficulty figuring out exactly what to do to make a remote connection to the MariaDB database.  I do have "bind-address=0.0.0.0" added to /etc/my.cnf.d and MariaDB does have port 3306 listed, after adding it.   Been going through a lot of different guides but haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing.  The only thing I'm noticing looking back is that TCP4 isn't being listed (just TCP6) Thanks for any help.

```
    [xxx]# sudo netstat -anp | grep 3306
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      32561/mysqld        


MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+


Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4545/sendmail: acce 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20057/httpd         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4487/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4545/sendmail: acce 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5308            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4783/cfservd        
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      32561/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 :::19091                :::*                    LISTEN      6434/macmnsvc      


[xxx]# firewall-cmd --add-port=3306/tcp 
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: '3306:tcp' already in 'public'
success
[root@xxxx# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3306/tcp
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 3306:tcp
success


MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+--------+------------------+
| User   | Host             |
+--------+------------------+
| bob | %                   |
| bob | [*local ip was here*].%    |
| mysql  | localhost        |
| root   | localhost        |
+--------+------------------+




vi /etc/my.cnf.d

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.4 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.4]




[xxx]# telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
X
5.5.5-10.4.6-MariaDB
                    VOiAG#vN
```

Comment: tcp6 ::: usually are referencing for IPv4 and IPv6. Also, on your telnet try, you show a correct connection aparently. Where did you see the problem? If you cannot connect from another machine, you can try to do mysql -h <lan ip> for test connection over LAN IPv4.

Comment: you have added the `bind-address=0.0.0.0` under `[galera]` section. Move it under `[mysqld]` and it will listen on ipv4